# Google Cloud Background Task with .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Im trying to find the best [compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) solution for converting(and compressing) files uploaded to a [Cloud Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets) as a background task.

Basically the user defines an xml file that tells this background task what to do and when the process is over it sends the link over email or dropbox.

Is there anything similar to [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) using .Net Core (inside GCP). Or what would be the preferred way to do it without waiting a lot of resources running a full VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions does not support .NET core today.

Running a small instance continuously on Compute Engine looks like the best solution on GCP today.  It will be the least expensive.  If you want GCP to manage your instances, then App Engine Flex can run .NET code too.